# How to put a treshold or enhancement on my colorbar plots ?

Tags: matlab, colorbar

I have two time series and I plot some similarity measures using colorbar. However, for one of my metrics, one of the results is very high compared to the other. Therefore, I can't distinguish enough variability in the charts. Is there a way to exclude some too high data from the figure ?

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

How about just apply a threshold before plotting:

```
%//Code assumes 2D image:

I_th = I;
I_th(I < threshold ) = threshold ; %//where threshold is a constant you define

imagesc(I_th);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can force the values above a certain threshold to be the threshold value.For example,

```
 A=[1 2 3 4 5];
 A(A>3)=3;
```

this will give you A=[1 2 3 3 3];

Alternatively, instead of excluding values, you might consider doing a color scale with a log transform, so that you can distinguish the colors better.
here is one example:
http://www.mikesoltys.com/2012/03/16/matlab-tip-logarithmic-color-scales-for-contour-and-image-plots/